# It's possible to use GWT in a Jruby app?

Tags: gwt, jruby

It's possible to use GWT in a Jruby app?

Comment: In what way? On the server side? It should work flawlessly. On the client side? Depends how JRuby works behind the scenes - GWT needs Java source files to generate JS code, so if JRuby could somehow provide the Java code it (probably) generates to GWT, then it *might* work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use GWT *in* any other programming language.

The key thing to understand is that "GWT" translates to "convert Java code to JavaScript"; in other words, it is fundamentally a compiler technology. While GWT offers other benefits, such as a rich collection of widgets, it's main purposes is running Java code *as* JavaScript.

However, between GWT and Google App Engine I am sure there are many ways to solve your problem. Can  you share any more details about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. I believed that GWT was some kind of widget java library, but i see now that is a java compiler. Thanks to all.

Comment: There is one language in which you might be able to write GWT applications soon: Mirah (http://mirah.org). Mirah has both a JVM bytecode backend and a Java source backend, which means it can work with GWT.

But no, there's no way to use JRuby to write GWT applications.